# Does a "advsecurity" license enables "crypto isakmp" on a Cisco C891F?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-15, cisco-isr

As the title says,

Does a "advsecurity" license enables "crypto isakmp" on a Cisco C891F?

This is the show license output:

```
Index 1 Feature: advipservices
    Period left: Life time
    License Type: Permanent
    License State: Active, In Use
    License Count: Non-Counted
    License Priority: Medium
Index 2 Feature: advsecurity
Index 3 Feature: ios-ips-update
    Period left: Not Activated
    Period Used: 0  minute  0  second
    License Type: EvalRightToUse
    License State: Not in Use, EULA not accepted
    License Count: Non-Counted
    License Priority: None
Index 4 Feature: MEM-8XX-512U1GB
    Period left: Not Activated
    Period Used: 0  minute  0  second
    License Type: EvalRightToUse
    License State: Not in Use, EULA not accepted
    License Count: Non-Counted
    License Priority: None
```

This is the abbreviated show version output:

```
Cisco IOS Software, C800 Software (C800-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.3(3)M6, 
RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2015 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue 04-Aug-15 05:50 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.4(1r)T1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

License Information for 'c800'
  License Level: advipservices   Type: Permanent
  Next reboot license Level: advipservices
```

I currently cannot use "crypto isakmp" and I believe it is due to not having this license.

Will the "advsecurity" license enable it or is it not supported on this hardware?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.
I've purchased the license upgrade with my ISP since they rent me this router.